# Can't get menu to function properly

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get the menu working right and get it responsive. I made the original layout on a 24" monitor and I am currently working on my 17" laptop.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EDtH.jpg

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bebasregular';
    src: url('fonts/bebas/bebas-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fonts/bebas/bebas-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansbold';
    src: url('fonts/opensans/opensans-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fonts/opensans/opensans-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ubuntubold';
    src: url('fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-b-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-b-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ubuntulight';
    src: url('fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-l-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-l-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ubunturegular';
    src: url('fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-r-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fonts/ubuntu/ubuntu-r-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansregular';
    src: url('fonts/opensans/opensans-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fonts/opensans/opensans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'myriadpro_regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Myriad Pro Regular'), url('fonts/myriad/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.woff') format('woff');
}

.window-size
{
    width: 1600px;
    height: 756px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0px;
}

div.top-header
{
    background-color: #ff6200;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    line-height: 10px;
}

.left-header1{
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #be3600;
    font-family: bebasregular;
    font-weight: 200;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 320px;
}

.left-header2{
    font-size: 23px;
    color: white;
    font-family: bebasregular;
    font-weight: 200;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.right-header1{
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #be3600;
    font-family: bebasregular;
    font-weight: 200;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 320px;
}

.right-header2{
    font-size: 23px;
    color: white;
    font-family: bebasregular;
    font-weight: 200;
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.breadcrumbs{
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 48px;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
    font-family: ubuntubold;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.breadcrumbs-plain{
    color: #adadad;
    padding-left: 320px;
    font-family: ubunturegular;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.contact-title{
    font-family: open_sansbold;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #ff6200;
    padding-left: 320px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.lorem{
    font-family: ubuntulight;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #878787;
    padding-left: 320px;
    padding-right: 320px;
    margin-top: 5px;

}

.split-left{
    width: 475px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 320px;
}

.split-right{
    width: 470px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    right: 0;
    padding-right: 560px;
}

.split-title{
    color: #ff6200;
    font-family: open_sansregular;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.contact-rule{
    width: 470px;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 20px;
    border-top: 6px solid #525252;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.reach-rule{
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 20px;
    border-top: 6px solid #525252;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.fullname-textbox{
    width: 470px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px;
    border-color: #ededed;
    text-indent: 10px;
    font-family: ubuntulight;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.half-textbox-email{
    width: 228px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px;
    border-color: #ededed;
    text-indent: 10px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    font-family: ubuntulight;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.half-textbox-phone{
    width: 228px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px;
    border-color: #ededed;
    text-indent: 10px;
    font-family: ubuntulight;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.message{
    width: 469px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px;
    border-color: #ededed;
    text-indent: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: ubuntulight;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.submit{
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #ff6200;
    width: 100px;
    height: 36px;
    border: 0px;
    font-family: open_sansbold;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.coalition{
    font-family: myriadpro_regular;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #595959;
}

.social-media
{
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.fa{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 10px; !important;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 2px;
}

.fa:hover{
    background-color: #595959;
}

.fa-facebook{
    background: #d0d0d0;
    color: white;
}

.fa-twitter{
    background: #d0d0d0;
    color: white;
}

.fa-pinterest{
    background: #d0d0d0;
    color: white;
}

.fa-linkedin{
    background: #d0d0d0;
    color: white;
}

h2.logo{
    font-size: 53px;
    color: black;
    font-family: bebasregular;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 320px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.logo2{
    font-size: 53px;
    color: #ff6200;
    font-family: bebasregular;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}

.nav-menu {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 34px;
    padding-bottom: 34px;
    color: #333333;
    top: 0px;
}

.navbar{
    margin-right: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 850px;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

ul li{
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-family: myriadpro_regular;
}
ul li:hover ul li{
    display: block;
    border: 0px;
    font-family: open_sansbold;
}

ul li:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ff6200;
}

ul li ul li{
    font-size: 14px;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 102px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: open_sansregular;
    left: 25px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 200;
}

ul li ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    font-family: open_sansbold;
}

ul li ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 102px;
    font-family: open_sansregular;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.80">
    <title>Job Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body class="window-size">
<div class="top-header">
    <h2 class="left-header1">CALL US NOW! <span class="left-header2"> 385.154.11.28.35</span></h2>
    <h2 class="right-header1">LOGIN <span class="right-header2"> SIGNUP</span></h2>
</div>
<div class="nav-menu">
    <h2 class="logo">YOUR<span class="logo2">LOGO</span></h2>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul class="list1">
            <li><a>TITLE 7</a></li>
            <li><a>TITLE 6</a></li>
            <li><a>TITLE 5</a></li>
            <li><a>TITLE 4</a></li>
            <li><a>TITLE 3</a></li>
            <li><a>TITLE 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>SUBMENU 1</a></li>
                    <li><a>SUBMENU 2</a></li>
                    <li><a>SUBMENU 3</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>SUBMENU 1</a></li>
                            <li><a>SUBMENU 2</a></li>
                            <li><a>SUBMENU 3</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a>TITLE 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <p class="breadcrumbs-plain"> Home / Who we are / <span style="color: black"> Contact</span></p>
    <p class="contact-title">Contact</p>
    <p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis orci sed tortor porta porta. Curabitur rutrum bibendum pretium. Nulla cursus pulvinar nisi sed imperdiet.
        Sed quis pharetra dui. Pellentesque lobortis, est sed fermentum efficitur, turpis elit porta lorem, in ornare dui velit et orci.</p>
</div>
<div class="split-left">
    <h2 class="split-title">CONTACT US</h2>
    <hr class="contact-rule">
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name *" class="fullname-textbox"><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone *" class="half-textbox-phone">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email *" class="half-textbox-email"><br>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message *" class="message"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="split-right">
    <h2 class="split-title">REACH US</h2>
    <hr class="reach-rule">
    <p class="coalition">
        <span style="font-size: 16pt; line-height: 40px;">Coalition Skills Test</span><br>
        535 La Plata Street<br>
        4200 Argentina<br><br>
        Phone: 385.1514.28.38<br>
        Fax: 385.154.35.66.78
    </p>
    <div class="social-media">
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To make it responsive: use % in units or flexbox layout. Hide menu items by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you can use flex-box concept or grid for your responsiveness which you can find flex-box quick tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) and for grid you can go [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

and second of all for your hoverable dropdown to work fine you can find very good ideas in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp)